# How can I rotate and reflect a molecule plot?

Tags: graphics, chemistry

Consider:

```
MoleculePlot[Molecule[Entity["Chemical", "Theobromine"]]]
```

[image: Structural diagram in a vertical orientation]

How can I rotate and reflect it? This is my current method:

```
img=Image[MoleculePlot[Molecule[Entity["Chemical", "Theobromine"]]]];
ImageRotate[ImageReflect[img]]
```

[image: The molecule is rotated, but the atom labels are now in the wrong orientation]

I would like two improvements on my current method:

1. The result is no longer a `Graphics` object. Instead I would like to retain the same `Head` (i.e., `Graphics`).
2. I want to retain the orientation of the atom labels as they were in the first plot, i.e., the "right way up".

Comment: Is this for `Graphics[]` in general, or for `MoleculePlot[]` in particular? If the latter, you can do `MoleculeModify[mol, "ComputeAtomDiagramCoordinates"]` and then transform the coordinates of those before feeding to `MoleculePlot[]`.

Comment: @J.M. It for `MoleculePlot` here. It's seem `"TransformAtomCoordinates"` can help. But it doesn't seem to work in 2D

Comment: Yes, that would be a good suggestion to make to support.

Comment: BTW, if one executes `MoleculePlot[Molecule[Entity["Chemical", "Theobromine"]]]` and then tries Menu/theme, one sees   not working `Automatic, Web, Minimal,...,Default` instead of `Aromatic, Monochrome, ....`.

Comment: @user, report that to Support if you can reproduce it (I could not), making sure to include the version you are using and your OS.

Comment: @J.M. Report for what? Did I miss something?

Comment: yode: user was (apparently) complaining right above my comment that the prompt for `PlotTheme` in `MoleculePlot` was not giving the right choices.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

## [`MoleculeValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MoleculeValue.html)`[m1, "AtomDiagramCoordinates"]`

If the idea is to change the [`MoleculePlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MoleculePlot.html) (2D diagram) as described in the question *after the edit*, then one can use:

```
Block[
    {
        chem=Entity["Chemical", "Theobromine"],
        tr =  ReflectionTransform[{1, -1}],
        coords,
        m1,m2
    },
    m1 = Molecule[chem];
    coords=  MoleculeValue[m1, "AtomDiagramCoordinates"];
    m2 = Molecule[chem
            , AtomDiagramCoordinates->tr@coords
        ];
    MoleculePlot/@{m1,m2}
]
```

[image]

---

Credit goes to @J.M for inspiring this answer, and for the much more compact alternative offered in the comments

```
{mol,coords} = EntityValue[Entity["Chemical","Theobromine"]
                    ,{"Molecule","VertexCoordinates"}
                ];
MoleculePlot[
    Molecule[
        mol
        ,AtomDiagramCoordinates->ReflectionTransform[{1,-1}][coords]
    ]
]
```

Comment: Since this is coming from an `Entity[]`, an alternative method goes like this: `{mol, coords} = EntityValue[Entity["Chemical", "Theobromine"], {EntityProperty["Chemical", "Molecule"], EntityProperty["Chemical", "VertexCoordinates"]}];
coords = RotationTransform[Pi/2][Standardize[coords, Mean, 100 &]];
MoleculePlot[Molecule[mol, AtomDiagramCoordinates -> coords]]`. The current version is of course more generically applicable.

Comment: @J.M. More little concise:`{mol,coords}=EntityValue[Entity["Chemical","Theobromine"],{"Molecule","VertexCoordinates"}];MoleculePlot[Molecule[mol,AtomDiagramCoordinates->ReflectionTransform[{1,-1}][coords]]]`

Comment: @J.M., no need for variables and lingering definitions if you do `MoleculePlot[Molecule[#1,AtomDiagramCoordinates->ReflectionTransform[{1,-1}]@#2]]&@@EntityValue[Entity["Chemical","Theobromine"],{"Molecule","VertexCoordinates"}]`

Comment: Both @yode's and your method are good if the molecule is already "centered" at the origin, like in the case of most of the `Entity[]`-derived coordinates. Otherwise, you need the `Standardize[]` step.

Answer (score 5):

## [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html)

If the idea is to transform the [`Graphics`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html), as described in the original wording of the question, then I use [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html)

```
With[
    {
        gr = MoleculePlot[Molecule[Entity["Chemical", "Theobromine"]]],
        tr =  ReflectionTransform[{1, -1}]
    },
    ReplaceAll[gr
        ,{
            FilledCurve[a_,{b_}]:>FilledCurve[a,{TranslationTransform[Mean[tr[b]]- Mean[b] ][b]}],
            List[a_Real,b_Real]:> tr[{a,b}]
        }
    ]
]
```

[image]